# Counting if range matches ranged criteria 1:1

Tags: google-sheets

I have an ongoing scoreboard with a friend for a game we play. It looks like this:

```
                A                    B      C       D        E          F
   +-----------------------------+-------+------+--------+--------+------------+
 1 | Through the Ages Scoreboard |       |      |        |        |            |
   +-----------------------------+-------+------+--------+--------+------------+
 2 | Game title                  | Kevin | M    | First? | Winner | Difference |
   +-----------------------------+-------+------+--------+--------+------------+
 3 | thekoalaz's Game            | 174   | 213  | Kevin  | M      | 39         |
 4 | Game #0                     | 242   | 126  | Kevin  | Kevin  | 116        |
 5 | Game #1                     | 105   | 146  | Kevin  | M      | 41         |
 6 | Game #2                     | 158   | 135  | Kevin  | Kevin  | 23         |
 7 | Game #3                     | 149   | 145  | M      | Kevin  | 4          |
 8 | Game #4                     | 91    | 145  | Kevin  | M      | 54         |
 9 | Game #5                     | 211   | 187  | M      | Kevin  | 24         |
10 | Game #6                     | 160   | 158  | M      | Kevin  | 2          |
11 | Game #7                     | 154   | 215  | Kevin  | M      | 61         |
12 | Game #8                     | 169   | 177  | M      | M      | 8          |
13 | Game #9                     | 135   | 129  | M      | Kevin  | 6          |
14 | Game #10                    | 156   | 262  | Kevin  | M      | 106        |
15 | Game #11                    | 205   | 171  | M      | Kevin  | 34         |
16 | Game #12 (2)                | 186   | 203  | Kevin  | M      | 17         |
17 |                             |       |      |        |        |            |
   +-----------------------------+-------+------+--------+--------+------------+
```

Where there's space at the end of the board to add scores for future games.

**How do I count how many times the player who goes first wins?** In this case it should be 3: D4 = E4, D6 = E6, D12 = E12. Is this possible to do in a single formula? And I'd like to make adding future game scores "just work" with this as well.

Here, first is `{K;K;K;K;M;K;M;M;K;M;M;K;M;K}`
And winner is `{M;K;M;K;K;M;K;K;M;M;K;M;K;M}`

I tried `=COUNTIF($E$3:$E, $D$3:$D)`, but this gives me 7, which I presume is the same as `=COUNTIF($E$3:$E, $D$3)`, without the ranged criteria.

Other ranged criteria questions didn't seem to focus on this 1:1 necessity (or maybe I don't know how to word it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I used:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(D3:D=E3:E, E3:E<>"")
```

Let's break it down.

`D3:D=E3:E` (also expressible as `EQ(D3:D, E3:E)`) - equality. I tried to figure out the concept of testing equality of ranges, but the best thing I could find was [Microsoft's tutorial on array formulas](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7). What I can say is if you just put `=D3:D=E3:E` in your Google sheet, it will just be *one* of the results--the one that matches the row. It requires `=ArrayFormula(D3:D=E3:E)` to enter as the array of equality results.

`SUMPRODUCT` - Sums the product of corresponding array elements between multiple arrays. For example, `SUMPRODUCT({1,3}, {2,4}) = 1*2 + 2*4 = 10`. If used with one array, it would just aggregate the array's values. `TRUE=1` and `FALSE=0`, so when considering the array formula above, it will count how many times `D3:D=E3:E` is true. Ranges work as arrays, so maybe that's why wrapping the equality with `ArrayFormula(...)` isn't necessary

`E3:E<>""` - Another array formula testing if the E cell is not empty (`<>` is the "not equals" sign). Because I want this to automatically work for any new entries, `D3:D=E3:E` will evaluate true for any empty entries (empty=empty). Mutliplying these two array formulas together is effectively an AND operator--"sum this if Dn=En AND En is not empty". To convince you, here are the truth tables:

```
+-----+---+---+    +------+---+---+
| AND | T | F |    | MULT | 1 | 0 |
+-----+---+---+    +------+---+---+
| T   | T | F |    |    1 | 1 | 0 |
| F   | F | F |    |    0 | 0 | 0 |
+-----+---+---+    +------+---+---+
```